# Private Ethereum Node connection with Metamask

Tags: private-blockchain, metamask, rpc

I am able to connect using metamask localhost 8545 option, as well as computer within the intranet.

```
geth --identity "SK" --datadir data --networkid 18 console --rpc --rpcport 8545 --rpcaddr "0.0.0.0" --rpccorsdomain "*" --rpcapi "db,eth,net,web3,personal"
```

But I can't connection outside my NAT router.

I am very sure that I have enabled port forwarding for TCP/UDP 8545, and able to see that port externally.

May I know what might had gone wrong in my settings?

Answer (score 2):

try to use the option :

```
  --nat value           NAT port mapping mechanism (any|none|upnp|pmp|extip:<IP>) (default: "any")
```

if your router supports upnp go for :

```
--nat upnp
```

Comment: extip:<IP> works